# Problemas con el deploy de gh-pages y react- route-dom

Tags: reactjs

Tengo este componente que retorna las rutas de mis vistas, al hacer *deploy* no carga el *home*,le coloqué el **process.env.PUBLIC_URL** en la ruta del **"/"**, sí realiza la carga pero sin el no, y al actualizar una vista en *gh-pages* envía:

> error 404 no mantiene el hash

Código:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './views/Home';
import Projects from './views/Projects';
import Skills from './views/Skills'
import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all';
import '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
const App =(props)=> {
    console.log('initial history is: ', JSON.stringify(window.history))
  
    return (
      <Router>
  
      <Switch> 
        <Route exact path="/" component={()=> (<Home active={false}/>)}/>
        <Route exact path="/projects" component={() => <Projects active={true}/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/skills" component={()=> <Skills active={true}/>}/>
       </Switch>

</Router>

)
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

El fallo que veo es que estás utilizando la prop `component` de `Route` como si fuera el `render`, le estás pasando una función cuando espera un componente.

Debería ser algo así:

```
<Switch> 
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home)}/>
        <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects}/>
        <Route exact path="/skills" component={Skills}/>
</Switch>
```

Ahora si lo que quieres es que reciban la prop `active` entonces utiliza render.

```
<Switch> 
        <Route exact path="/" render={()=> (<Home active={false}/>)}/>
        <Route exact path="/projects" render={() => <Projects active={true}/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/skills" render={()=> <Skills active={true}/>}/>
</Switch>
```